# Form works in development but not production - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a voting platform that I'm building for my company and I am very close to finishing it but the actual voting is failing while in production. I've done all my migrating and everything, and it's still working in development.

Here are the logs I'm receiving from heroku:

> 2019-01-11T18:33:59.235681+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>   [2019-01-11T18:33:59.235579 #4]  INFO -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb] Started POST
>   "/ballots/13/votes" for 75.150.214.2 at 2019-01-11 18:33:59 +0000
>   2019-01-11T18:33:59.236373+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>   [2019-01-11T18:33:59.236296 #4]  INFO -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb] Processing by
>   VotesController#create as HTML 2019-01-11T18:33:59.236437+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-11T18:33:59.236378 #4]  INFO -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"Y/vAh2kYPskozS2yQn3Ky1fOq41abLUjlxho0Q+zXHSndVlaSfwYz7bdoqvintdBXrYNDhsbIduYICpUAx3/0g==",
>   "user_vote"=>"Why", "vote"=>{"comment"=>""}, "commit"=>"Cast Vote",
>   "ballot_id"=>"13"} 2019-01-11T18:33:59.239540+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>   [2019-01-11T18:33:59.239464 #4] DEBUG -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb]   Ballot Load (0.7ms)  SELECT 
>   "ballots".* FROM "ballots" WHERE "ballots"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id",
>   13], ["LIMIT", 1]] 2019-01-11T18:33:59.240333+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>   [2019-01-11T18:33:59.240244 #4]  INFO -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb] Completed 500 Internal Server
>   Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms) 2019-01-11T18:33:59.240846+00:00
>   app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-11T18:33:59.240770 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb]
>   2019-01-11T18:33:59.240917+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2019-01-11T18:33:59.240847 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb]
>   ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'comment' for
>   Vote.):' '2019-01-11T18:33:59.240981+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2019-01-11T18:33:59.240914 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb]
>   2019-01-11T18:33:59.241051+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2019-01-11T18:33:59.240987 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [772bc37c-00ee-43da-aa81-564d353553bb]
>   app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:10:in `create'
>   2019-01-11T18:34:07.533587+00:00 heroku[run.2070]: State changed from
>   up to complete bobby@bobby-Al

Here's my code for vote create

```
def create
    @ballot = Ballot.find(params[:ballot_id])
    @vote = @ballot.votes.new(user_vote: params[:user_vote], comment: params[:vote][:comment])
    @vote.user_id = current_user.id
    if !current_user.votes.find_by(ballot_id: params[:ballot_id])
        @vote.save
        redirect_to ballot_path(params[:ballot_id]) 
    else
        flash[:alert] = "You've already voted on this ballot"
        redirect_to ballot_path(params[:ballot_id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a migration problem, just make sure to run your migrations for the environment production on heroku like this:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Restart your app

```
heroku restart --app my_app_name
```

**Important**

If you generate a migration that creates a table and make a push to heroku, to add another column to that table you shouldn't modify that one, instead you should create another one for that.

When you run rake db:migrate, rails register that on the table schema_migrations, so if you modify a migrate that is already registered is not going to be executed again. This could be the case, check directly on your database and see if the column is there.

Comment: That's what I thought! But I checked my database and all of my old comments do have a nil "comment" attribute on my heroku database/production. I ran that command a few hours ago.

Comment: But the name of the model is Vote and is missing a comment attribute right?

Comment: Also, I just checked directly on heroku psql and the column comment is on the votes table for sure.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it's says in the log.

Comment: I did some digging and ran into some nonsense about a cached schema. I just needed a heroku restart. All set now.